# Symfony2 event listener as service

Tags: php, symfony

When defining an event listener as a service how do i define which function to use with which event?

services.yml:

```
kernel.listener.desktop_init:
    class: AirOS\TopBarModule\Listeners\InitAdminDesktopListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.listener }
```

listener class:

```
class InitAdminDesktopListener
{
    public function onInitAdminDesktop(InitAdminDesktopEvent $event)
    {
        $session = $event->getSession();
        $session->set('test2', 'im a test value!');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're most of the way there; what you need are `event` and `method` parameters for your tag (since Beta4 release):

```
kernel.listener.desktop_init:
    class: AirOS\TopBarModule\Listeners\InitAdminDesktopListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.listener, event: onInitAdminDesktop, method: onInitAdminDesktop }
```

Note that in the upcoming RC1 release of Symfony, you'll need to use `kernel.event_listener` instead of `kernel.listener` for the tag name (see the [UPDATE file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPDATE.md) for more details).

Comment: do I have to use kernel.listener or can I use something like: blah.listener.whatEvent ?